# FFMPEG Multiple Alpha Overlays

Tags: video, command-line, ffmpeg, video-processing

I have a few videos with alpha channels that I will like to overlay on top of each other. It's possible to get working with the following command

```
ffmpeg -i back.mov -i front.mov -filter_complex overlay -c:v png output.mov
```

However if I add another video to this it no longer works

```
ffmpeg -i back.mov -i front.mov -i front2.mov -filter_complex overlay -c:v png output.mov
```

Does anyone know a way of getting this to work? or would I have to output the first 2 layers and then run the code again with a new layer?

I will have more than 3 layers so looking for the most efficient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform successive overlays with the correct inputs at each turn,

```
ffmpeg -i back.mov -i front.mov -i front2.mov -filter_complex [0][1]overlay[o];[o][2]overlay -c:v png out.mov
```

Comment: Thanks Gyan, that works great. 

Are you able to explain what is going on here and what each [0] [1] [2] [o], i assume [0] [1] [2] refer to the respective videos? 

So it [0][1]overlay[o] <-- takes first video and overlays 1 and outputs file o

[o][2]overlay <- takes file [o] and overlays 2 then outputs the file to out.mov?